# Set up/run project with docker and databases

Tags: php, docker

I have been struggling for a few days to understand how to launch a project I was given and I turn to you to get a clearer picture. 
It is an internal portal web project that allows you to connect MantisBT and Jenkins as plugins.

So I'm trying with Docker to launch a MantisBT image with `image: vimagick/mantisbt:latest` and a MariaDB image.

Into the code project, I have a file `mysql_cnf.php` that tells me important info:

```
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$hostname = "pc949";
$port = "3362";
$db_mantis = "bugtracker";
$SERVER_HTML = "https://OURSERVER/mantisCMS";
$MANTIS_SERVER_PATH =$SERVER_HTML.'/mantis';
```

I've made my `docker-compose.yml` as :

```
mantisbt:
  image: vimagick/mantisbt:latest
  ports:
    - "3362:8080"
  links:
    - db
  restart: always

db: 
  environment: 
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=bugtracker
    - MYSQL_USER=root
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
  image: mariadb
  ports: 
    - "3306:3306"
  restart: always
```

I can access the installations of MantisBT at the `http://localhost:3362/admin/install.php`.
I can connect to mySQL via `mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root -p` and create database.

But I still don't get how I can link what I'm doing and how I can run the code I have in Eclipse... I've created a configuration *Local Apache* which runs an `index.php` file at `http://localhost:8080` but it's still not linked.

Comment: you connect mysql form host or inside mantisbt?

Comment: I'm trying via MantisBT 
(still not working but working on it with user grants)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

`mysql -h db --protocol=tcp -u root -p`

or remove `--portocol`

`mysql -h db -u root -p`

Comment: `ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db'`.
I tried as well precising the port 3306

Comment: The only command working is `mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root -p`.
I've also this warning when I launch my docker-compose: `'db' entry 'bugtracker root@pc956' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode` that I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: Yes from host use `mysql -uroot -p` is enough but inside docker container, you have to use container name to communicate to each other, in you case you try to connect mysql inside **mantisbt**, you have to use db as a hostname, `mysql -h db -u root -p`

Comment: OK I've done the connection via the install page of MantisBT. And I got now the `config_inc.php'`
`<?php
$g_hostname               = 'db';
$g_db_type                = 'mysqli';
$g_database_name          = 'bugtracker';
$g_db_username            = 'alebouler';
$g_db_password            = 'xxxx';

$g_default_timezone       = 'Asia/Shanghai';

$g_crypto_master_salt     = 'xxxxxxxxx';`

Comment: well.. I still have the error `Unknown MySQL server host 'db'` when I run `mysql -h db -u root -p`

Comment: you have to go inside `mantisbt` to run that command, `docker exec -it mantisbt bash`, you can find your container name by `docker ps`

Comment: yes i managed to get see my db via the docker ! thanks a lot @kyaw-kyaw-soe